# Issue running cloud functions code locally using cloud functions shell

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to test my functions locally using cloud functions shell. I was successful in making the shell thing work for my code. I see that this doesn't require my code to be deployed to the cloud. But whenever I run the function through shell it's working fine but it is using the deployed code, not the local code(I am checking this by using console statements as shown in sample code). I am not able to invoke local code unless I deploy.

Also, in my cloud functions, I am using the onCreate method for a real-time database and writing back to the same real-time database. When I test locally using the shell, I input data files for the function and write back to the real-time database. So I am actually trying to write code and run it locally to write to a real-time database on the cloud. Is this achievable using shell without deploying functions?

My sample function looks like this:

```
export const myCloudFunction = functions.database.instance(getDatabaseIdentifier()).ref(PATH).onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

    console.log('local code invoked')
    // or
    console.log('deployed code invoked')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out since I am using typescript I need to transpile my code to javascript before I run the cloud functions shell.

The reason I thought it's invoking the deployed code is obvious as it is not actually invoking the deployed code but invoking the locally transpiled code which gets generated while I deploy to cloud. Now all I needed to do is transpile my code using the below command in my functions folder before I run the cloud functions shell.

```
// run this command in your functions folder 
   'npm run-script build'
```

This build generates transpiled javascript code in the 'lib' folder. Now we can run the below command to invoke the shell.

```
firebase functions:shell
```

Now we can emulate the local non deployed cloud functions and test them locally.

Check this medium post for detailed explanation:
https://medium.com/@moki298/test-your-firebase-cloud-functions-locally-using-cloud-functions-shell-32c821f8a5ce